# Unable to fold python comments with VIM

Tags: vim

I am trying to fold my python code using VIM like would normally happen automatically with PyCharm or Atom Text Editor.

I think these are the relevant lines in my .vimrc related to folding:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
```

I also have Python mode enabled, but from what I can tell this doesnt seem to make a difference with folding, as I've had this same problem with and without it.

The folding mostly works as i would expect, except when I have a block of commented text. I want the entire block (code and comments) to be folded together. Attached are pictures of what it looks like folded and unfolded. To fold and unfold I am using z+M and z+R.

For some reason Vim seems to treat a commented line differently than an uncommented one when it looks at the tab indentation level, and from what I have read I still don't see why this is. Can someone explain how I can fold these comments with the surrounding code?

[image][image]

Comment: I suspect this may be related to the `cinkeys` options but I'm not sure `cinkeys` is obeyed when one isn't in a C file... Can you try `set cinkeys-=0#` and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: just tried it, still the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix vim to properly indent folds containing Python comment lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993455/how-do-i-fix-vim-to-properly-indent-folds-containing-python-comment-lines)

Comment: thank you that solved it